# Dynamic Proxy Object Creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, .net-4.0, proxy

Recently I have been looking for a way to create proxy objects that reflect the properties of other objects programmatically. However I have been unable to find any information on how to do something like this, I believe it should be possible as I have noticed in EntityFramework performing LINQ operations returns proxy objects with the same properties which can be cast directly to the type that they represent.

Basically I am looking for this same functionality and if anyone could explain how it works I would be greatful.

Pseudo code:

```
object proxy = GetDynamicProxy(typeof(ProxyType));
```

So basically I am looking for a way to get an object that represents the `ProxyType` and a method like `GetDynamicProxy` to get it.

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Can you provide some code or pseudocode to clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean ICloneable/MemberwiseClone?

Comment: Added some pseudo code to try and make my desires clearer.

Comment: How's the pseudo different to Activator.CreateInstance?

Comment: Well the object created will not be the same Type as the ProxyType, it will be a POCO object, which just reflects the properties, removing all events and interfaces.

Comment: dynamic is a sort-of proxy. At least it uses reflection and the DLR to detect members on a CLR type. You can simply inherit from DynamicObject and perform your custom logic. You wont have static checking or intellisense support though. Else, take a look at some mocking frameworks. Please note that almost all implementations are far from solid (think static and sealed classes)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how EntityFramework generates its POCO proxies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF the proxy are generated by dynamically deriving from the entity type and dynamically implementing the code. You need to be looking at dynamically compiled assemblies, types and lambdas. System.Reflection.Emit is your friend (???). Here is a link that should help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50

Answer (score 0):

If your objectcontext has ProxyCreationEnabled set to true then

```
yourContext.CreateObject<YourType>()
```

will create a dynamic proxy version of your type and you can populate the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx